# npm: not found when building Docker container

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I had a developer create a Docker file for me -- and it's worked for months flawlessly. Recently I formatted my mac to clean some space, and re-ran the command to build the Docker container, and I got the following error:

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNUSc.png)

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. It builds properly on my other machines, but it's giving me a hard time on this new fresh install. I'm not a technical person, thanks everyone.

Comment: Copy error logs instead of screenshotting them...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your screenshot it seems like you are not installing npm.
Please add npm to your apt-get install RUN command.